# Changes in code doesn't take effect when i build apk

Tags: android

My app layout had some problems I fixed it and ran the app, it looks fine in emulator but when I build an apk and install it on a real device(Pixel 2 XL) it installs the old version. I delete the apk and the app from the real device and then install the new apk, I even changed the version code and apk name but still, it installs the old version.

The real device I'm using is Huawei mate 10 pro with Android version 9.0.0 Pie.

I tried many things but it isn't working, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try building app to mobile instead of emulator. Don't make APK and see if problem still persists

Comment: make sure your instant run is off

Comment: The huawei device isn't shown in my connected devices, i installed the usb driver for huawei but still it doesn't show, that's why i build apk and install it on device. Although i can run the app directly on samsung devices the problem is with a particular layout which the Huawei mate 10 uses that's why i have to use that as my testing device.

Comment: @Priyankagb It's already turned off.

Answer (score 0):

try Sync Project with Gradle file and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Before uninstalling previous version of the app, try to clear the cache and then uninstall the app. After that install new version of the app.